# AND / OR formula not working properly in data validation tool

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to type a formula in the data validation tool but it's not working. Can someone please tell me the issue?

Wanted logic is :

IF cell A109 = "test1" or "test2" AND cell B109 is empty, then, I dont want to be able to fill cell B111.

My formula :

`=AND(OR(A109="test1", A109="test2"), NOT(ISBLANK(B109)))`

Why isn't it working?

Comment: does B109 have a formula that returns an empty string`""`?

Comment: try: `=AND(OR(A109="test1", A109="test2"),B109<>"")`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your proposition... it pops the error no matter what is in 'A109' ! I want the error to run only if A109 == test1 or test2 ... @ScottCraner

Comment: then your logic is backward.  If it returns TRUE it will allow entry, you want the reverse: `=NOT(AND(OR(A109="test1", A109="test2"),B109<>""))`

Comment: Thank you again... but now, there's no error, no matter what isinside A109! ....

Comment: `=NOT(AND(OR(A109="test1", A109="test2"),B109=""))`

Comment: this one worked !!!! Thank you so much !!!!